# Apache2 is inactive - need to change python2 port to a different port

Tags: apache2

I was experimenting with SET when I unintentionally uninstalled apache2. I then reinstalled it and checked the status. It said `Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2017-05-21 15:01:20 EDT; 20min ago`. I had also saw this: `(98)Address already in use`.

I then ran the command `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80`. It told me that python2 was using port 80. Can anyone please tell me how to change the python2 port, or anything I can do to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What is running on port 80? (Which program) If it's Django or a webserver you can edit it's configuration.

Comment: Saying that a python instance is bound on port 80 doesn't tell anything about the type of software which is running on the interpreter. Because that program might be started on boot and have it's own configuration files. You must know what it is, port 80 is very important.

Comment: I do not know what is running on port 80, as I am new to linux, but I think it is a web server, I am trying to get SET to bind to port 80 but it isn't because something else is using port 80 not allowing me to complete a SET action